# Search in JS Array, show position of rarest and most freuquently items

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

I have this array. I know how to search for values.

But what I need here is something different, I couldn't figure out how to do it. I don't know where to start.

The current event is 0000000010.

I need the rarest six numbers in the array on their last position from smallest event number to th highest event number (10).
As an example: Number 40 is seen few times. In event 8 and event 5. So the last position would be in event 8. But I need here only the number, which is one of the six numbers, that are shown the rarest.

And I need the most frequently six numbers.

```
"results": 
    [
        {event: "0000000010", draw: [16,37,2,24,48,41]},
        {event: "0000000009", draw: [49,1,10,17,41,23]},
        {event: "0000000008", draw: [40,11,16,47,1,33]},
        {event: "0000000007", draw: [9,32,27,41,14,4]},
        {event: "0000000006", draw: [29,26,44,46,19,41]},
        {event: "0000000005", draw: [31,40,10,13,6,27]},
        {event: "0000000004", draw: [5,38,30,1,15,10]},
        {event: "0000000003", draw: [39,48,9,2,34,1]},
        {event: "0000000002", draw: [6,23,39,31,16,14]},
        {event: "0000000001", draw: [14,16,13,15,2,25]},
        {event: "0000000000", draw: [18,22,13,12,19,47]}
    ]
```

Comment: please add some more information. whar means rarest? from a single or from all or just from a selection and why 40? what do you mean by getting the event? please post the wanted result and how it is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a number=> count map:

```js
var events=[
        {event: "0000000010", draw: [16,37,2,24,48,41]},
        {event: "0000000009", draw: [49,1,10,17,41,23]},
        {event: "0000000008", draw: [40,11,16,47,1,33]},
        {event: "0000000007", draw: [9,32,27,41,14,4]},
        {event: "0000000006", draw: [29,26,44,46,19,41]},
        {event: "0000000005", draw: [31,40,10,13,6,27]},
        {event: "0000000004", draw: [5,38,30,1,15,10]},
        {event: "0000000003", draw: [39,48,9,2,34,1]},
        {event: "0000000002", draw: [6,23,39,31,16,14]},
        {event: "0000000001", draw: [14,16,13,15,2,25]},
        {event: "0000000000", draw: [18,22,13,12,19,47]}
    ];
    
 //create hash map
    
    var hash={};
    
    events.forEach(function(event){
    
        event.draw.forEach(function(number){
          hash[number]={number,value:(hash[number]||{value:0}).value+1};
        });
   });
   
 //sort
   
var sorted=Object.values(hash).sort((a,b)=>a.value-b.value).map(el=>el.number);

console.log(sorted);
```